# Symmetrical power supply: Rail fuses useful or dangerous?

Tags: audio, analog, circuit-design, safety, fuses

I'm designing/testing power amp stuff with symmetrical power supplies (43V-0-43V). In the next future I'm planning to control all safety/healthy stuff (like over current / over voltage / temperature etc.) using a microcontroller/relais but...

... actually I'm using now nothing but **only a pair of slow fuses on the supply rails**. (beside one mains fuse) I saw, there are also some commercial designs using them.
[image]

Now I'm considering if this is a good idea at all to use those two independent fuses - even in the test phase. **Because if only one fuse one single rail blows (instead of both), the supplied amp circuits /opamps will be powered unsymetrically, bias will be shifted dramatically, DC offset on the outputs will occur, semiconductors will get hot etc...**

1. Do these independent rails fuses really make sense?
2. Are there any methods to make them blow both simultaneaously when failing?
3. Are there any simple and working over current protection methods for symmetrical PSUs?

Comment: Previous company I worked for has a similar issue. We had an SCR across both rails and some logic to detect asymmetry outside of specifications which would trigger the SCR to blow both fuses. If you want the user to be able to replace the fuses and keep going, you need to provide SSOA protection which we didn’t do the SCR would stay shorted due to damage, but the event was so rare and components had to be replaced anyway.

Comment: A two-pole circuit breaker comes to mind. I don't know how easy they are to get at such low powers, though. winny's idea makes sense, though; I'd use some logic and latching relays to break the circuit if one fuse blows, though, rather than forcing current to blow the other fuse as well. But that's just my preference.

Answer (score 1):

Fuses are not intended to protect the circuit, but to prevent a possible fire. While the 135W that one rail could deliver regularly is allready sufficient to start a fire, the energy in the case of a short curcuit would be much higher.

Your question leaves open whether it is a single copy or a prototype for a whole series.

**Development**
Building an amplifier and then turning the power switch on is a very bad idea. As a teennager a friend gave me a 1000W amplifier kit and instructed me to assemble it. I did so - when I turned the switch around, there was a loud bang and light went off. The mains fuse, output transistors, driver transistors and two multimeters - all toast.

1. Either you need an adjustable dual power supply or a variac.
2. Then you must short the audio input (no signal) and put ammeters on both power rails.
3. Now you can slowly increase the voltage starting from zero. Watch continiously the ammeters and control the circuit for hot parts and smoke signals.
4. Switch power off, wait until the capacitors are empty
5. Connect the speaker and redo point 3.
6. Switch power off, wait until the capacitors are empty
7. Connect audio source with volume 0
8. Switch power on
9. Raise slowly the audio volume while whatching the circuit.

**Finished amplifier circuit**
Now it's time to analyze the circuit and look what happens when one half of the power goes away. I would pay particular attention to whether the speaker could be damaged.

Now one must consider that if the fuse triggers, something went broken anyway and a repair is inevitable. For a series product you could decide that two fuses (plus one for the primary side of the transformer) are enough and everything else is too expensive. If you're a thrifty guy you could even decide that a single fuse on the primary side is sufficient. For your individual item you can of course take further protective measures.

I don't see any other feasable option than the two already named in the comments to your question.

- Two mechanicaly coupled circuit breakers
- A voltage monitoring circuit that triggers a thyristor to blow the other fuse to

Answer (score 0):

For the protection of a circuit from unsafe input or output conditions, there should be a specification to design this protection. If you know these then define them and design a protection circuit. Fuses won't meet this requirement. e.g. voltage and tracking regulator with DC OK status to enable/disable current at a controlled slew rate while detecting input and output currents with thermal protection...Fuses can be secondary protection

This reliability improvement comes at a cost but like the LM317 has OCP and OTP, it does not have input SCP ( short circuit protection ) so a reverse power diode must be added. In this case the cost is low.